# Algebra : How to prove propositions using conjugate amd modulus properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When given propositions to prove such as the following question:
prove that $|z+i| = |z-i|$ if $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Would I have to prove this proposition without substituting $z$ for a complex number?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple: it is enough to prove $\lvert z+ \mathrm i\rvert^2=\lvert z- \mathrm i\rvert^2$.  Now, since $z$ is real, we have $\lvert z+ \mathrm i\rvert^2= (z+ \mathrm i) (\overline{z+\mathrm i})=(z+ \mathrm i)(z-\mathrm i) $, while  $\lvert z-\mathrm i\rvert^2=(z-\mathrm i)(z+\mathrm i) $.

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly NOT substitute a complex number for $z$ (not the other way around, anyway!) if you are asked to prove the identity for REAL valued $z$.

So - rephrasing - yes, you must prove that proposition without substituting some random real numbers for $z$. That will only prove the proposition for the few values you substituted, it will not prove it to be true for ALL real values of $z$. For that you need a more general, theoretical proof. Proofs are exceptionally rarely complete by just plugging in a few values and noticing that the proposition holds.

In this case, if $z$ is real, you can apply the definition of the absolute value of a complex number, because the real part and the imaginary part of $z + i$ and $z - i$ are plainly clear. It all reduces to the obvious identity $\sqrt{z^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{z^2 + (-1)^2}$, which holds for ALL possible values of $z$, simply because $1^2 = (-1)^2$ regardless of $z$.